# A Better way to write a Switch in PHP?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I use this example below to ask how to pass an array into a Switch instead of listing them all out like this?

Perhaps if I had an array being fetched from a database for all the 'pages' as page.

I figured this method wasn't the most elegant approach.

```
switch($_GET['page'])
{
case 'home':
    include('home.php');
    break;
case 'oem-customers':
    include('oem-customers.php');
    break;
case 'job-shop': 
    include('job-shop.php');        
    break;
case 'anodized-magnet-coils':
    include('anodized-magnet-coils.php');
    break;
case 'design':
    include('design.php');
    break;
case 'services':
    include('services.php');
    break;
case 'black-foil':
    include('black-foil.php');
    break;  
case 'contact':
    include('contact.php');
    break;
case 'order';
    include('order.php');
    break;
default: 
    include('home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
switch($_GET['page'])
{
case 'home':
case 'oem-customers':
case 'job-shop': 
case 'anodized-magnet-coils':
case 'design':
case 'services':
case 'black-foil':
case 'contact':
case 'order';
    include("$_GET[page].php");
    break;
default: 
    include('home.php');
}
```

Comment: We posted exactly at the same time! Nice thinking btw.

Comment: `include("{$_GET['page']}.php");` would be cleaner.  I believe your current version raises a notice.

Comment: $_GET must be filtered/sanitized like there's no tomorrow in this case. even then, its still insecure.

Comment: $_GET comes from the request. It is user-posted information, so you cant trust it. You must sanitize it for anything - leave aside what you are doing. You are feeding $_GET value directly to a include in the server. Imagine what happens when a malicious user sends a malicious string that involves file or directory structure. It will be fed directly into php's include, and from there to server filesystem.

Comment: @unity100 A malicious string would go to default case including `home.php`

Comment: There are exploits which seek to go around string matching in case or if or any other patterns at that level. It is not wise to leave it to php's string matching until that point.

Answer (score 3):

Example with an array :

```
$pages = array(
    'oem-customers',
    'job-shop',
    'anodized-magnet-coils',
    'design',
    'services',
    'black-foil',
    'contact',
    'order' 
);

if(in_array($_GET['page'], $pages)){
    include($_GET['page'].'.php');
}else{
    include('home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a mapping:

```
$mapping = array(
   'home' => 'home',
   'oem-customers' => 'oem-customers',
   #....
);

$page = $_GET['page'];
$file = isset($mapping[$page]) ? $mapping[$page] : 'home';
include($file.'.php');
```

Or first look up the file, check if the file exists, and perhaps use extra mapping if needed. Note: Sanitize the input, users could send `../../etc/whatever` in the request.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
switch($_GET['page']){
  case 'home':case 'oem-customers':case 'job-shop':case 'anodized-magnet-coils':
  case 'black-foil':case 'services':case 'design':case 'contact':case 'order':
    include($_GET['page'].'.php');
    break;
  default: 
    include('home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well, you seem to have a pretty good match between `$_GET['page']` and the filename of the page; an easy thing to do is:

```
   $toInclude = "{$_GET['page']}.php";
   include($toInclude);
```

of course, you want to be careful; someone could trick you by passing something bad in `page`, like '../../some_other_project/delete_all_data.php'. so can keep a validation list of all of the pages you allow:

```
   $validPages = array('order.php', 'home.php');
   if (!in_array($toInclude, $validPages))
       $toInclude = 'home.php';
```

Answer (score 2):

If it were me I'd move your scripts that can be requested into a `requests/` folder and do the following:

```
$script = basename( $_GET['page'] );
$dir = 'requests/';
$file = $dir . $script . '.php';
if ( !file_exists( $file ) ) {
  $file = $dir . 'home.php';
}
include( $file );
```

1. Much more compact than anything else.
2. Will auto update whenever you add a new page.
3. Built-in check for existence of file before include.
4. Safe due to the containing `requests/` folder and `basename()`.

Comment: eheh nice to know i'm not alone :)

Comment: heh, yeah.. I'm not one for typing huge arrays that keep having to be extended. A computer is supposed to make things easier after all ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest a total different way:

```
$base_path = '/path/to/dir/';
$req = basename($_GET['page'] . '.php');
$page = $base_path . $req;
$file = file_exists($page) ? $page : $base_path . 'home.php'; 
include($file);
```

Comment: @ben: ok added basename for security :)

Comment: There is a slight bug in this, you need `$req` to return as `$base_path . $req` from the `ternary operator` / `inline if statement` - once that's sorted it's a perfectly good answer, not that I'm biased in any way... :)